# how to write elisp helper function for refactoring

Tags: emacs, closures

I am pretty new to emacs and I am not sure I understand what lisp should actually behave.

Suppose I have two function

`(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
    add-to-list (make-local-variable 'company-backends) 'company-jedi))
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
    add-to-list (make-local-variable 'company-backends) 'company-tern))`

I wrote the following function

`(defun auto-complete (mode-hook backend)
    (add-hook mode-hook
       (lambda ()
    add-to-list (make-local-variable 'company-backends) backend)))
(auto-complete 'js2-mode-hook 'company-tern)`

but it does not work. I looked online and I found it is because elisp does not have closure! 
So, how should I refactor these two code block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add-to-list` is a function, so you need to use it with parentheses, as `(add-to-list...)`.   Or invoke it using `funcall` or `apply`.

Elisp *has* closures.  Do *one* of the following:

With file-local-variable `lexical-binding` non-`nil`:

```el
(defun auto-complete (mode-hook backend)
  (add-hook mode-hook
    (lambda ()
       (add-to-list (make-local-variable 'company-backends) backend))))
```

With lexical binding you get a closure, which encapsulates an environment where variable `backend` is defined.  Its value in that environment is the value it has when the closure is created, but the variable remains when the anonymous function is used - you can use it as a variable.

See the Elisp manual, node [Using Lexical Binding](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html).

Regardless of the value of `lexical-binding`:

```el
(defun auto-complete (mode-hook backend)
  (add-hook mode-hook
     `(lambda ()
       (add-to-list (make-local-variable 'company-backends) ',backend))))
```

In this case, there is ***no closure***, and there is ***no variable `backend`*** in the function. Instead, that variable is *replaced by its value* at the time and in the context where the `defun` is evaluated. You can use this if you do not need to use the variable when the anonymous function is called, and all you need is its value (at the time of definition of that function).

If you use a closure then the anonymous function can be byte-compiled. If you use the variable-replacement technique then it cannot - in that case, you are not creating an anonymous function at the time of `defun` evaluation (or for byte-compilation). Instead, you are creating a *list*: `(lambda...)`, and that list is later interpreted as a function.